# How do I insert HTML-Formatted Strings into a Microsoft Word Document using Visual Basic while preserving formatting?

Tags: html, vba, ms-word

I use Visual Basic and an automation interface to retrieve strings from an external application. These strings contain simple html formatting codes (<b>, <i>, etc.).
Is there any easy function in Visual Basic for Word to insert these strings into a word document and convert the html formatting codes to word formatting?

Answer (score 14):

Here's a link to add HTML to the clipboard using VB:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274326

Once you have the HTML on the clipboard, paste it into your word doc using something like this:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.PasteSpecial ,,,,WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML
```

This is pretty much the equivalent of you cutting and pasting it in manually.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274326 This link is down. Could you provide the code? Furthermore, it seems that WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML results in an error (code: 5342, The specific data type is unavailable)

Answer (score 2):

Use InsertFile

```
Set objdoc = objInsp.WordEditor
Set objword = objdoc.Application
Set objsel = objword.Selection
objsel.WholeStory
vs_html = "<html><body>" + vs_body + "</body></html>"
vs_file = "C:\temp\1.html"
Call DumptoFile(vs_file, "", vs_html, False)
RetVal = objsel.InsertFile(vs_file, , , False, False)
```

Comment: WOW! Simple and bulletproof. :D (Of course there will be some nuances toward using %TEMP%, or something, and we need some DumpToFile() solution, but that is widely available on the Net.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 2016.  The only thing that worked was Range.InsertFile(path).  Pasting Special didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no builtin function to do that in VBA. You will have to write it yourself, which would be not too difficult if you restirct it to parse `<b>, <i>, <a> and <p>,` for example. All other tags would have to be ignored.