# Microsoft Word 2007 Does Not Allow Special Characters In Its Hyperlinks

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, special-characters, urlencode, word-2007

I am trying to put a hyperlink in a MS Word document using MS Word 2007 which links to a URL that includes curly brackets ('{', '}') and ampersands ('&'). Word 2007, however, does not allow these characters. Nor does it allow percent signs ('%') either, so I cannot URL encode these characters.

Any suggestions on how to link to a URL which includes special characters? Specifically curly brackets and ampersands?

Comment: I was able to add a hyperlink (Insert->Hyperlink) in Word 2007 with both curly brackets and ampersands, they are URL encoded after, of course ...

Comment: Without percent signs, you're pretty much screwed - can't do any escaping in URL. Are you sure there's no way to get them into the link? (e.g. if you can't type them in, could you paste them? or is this "un-validation" done at save?)

Comment: ask this over on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting the links into the document as HTML as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161519/how-do-i-insert-html-formatted-strings-into-a-microsoft-word-document-using-visua/163511#163511)?

Answer (score 0):

MS-Word 2007 does allow special characters (including curly brackets and ampersands). It just has a validation regex that the URL did not comply when it had curly brackets and ampersands. Those were the only characters I removed before the URL validated, leading me to believe that they were the sole cause of the invalidation instead of the URL in its entirety. To make the problem even worse, MS-Word 2010 validated the URL which MS-Word 2007 did not.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this manually on a link by link basis but the process is ugly:

1. Change your word document from `blah.docx` to `blah.zip`
2. Unzip the file
3. Find the file `document.xml.rels`
4. Edit it in notepad. find your special characters and replace:

   - { = %7B
   - } = %7D
   - & = %26
   - # = %23
5. Save your edited file `document.xml.rels` (i.e. overwrite the current one)
6. ZIP the entire package back up
7. Rename your new ZIP file to `.docx`